# Angular 2 router global state change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a global event that we can use when state change/start that not per component unlike the [Component Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.github.io/router/lifecycle) ? like in UI-router:

```
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function() {})
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve, but it is possible to inject `Router` in your top level component and `.subscribe()` to it to get the stream of states.

I used it to build functionality that changes browser's title based on current state. That being said you can think about it as equivalent of `$stateChangeSuccess` and `$stateChangeFailure`events from Angular 1.

The code will be:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
    router.subscribe(successHandler, failureHandler);
}
```

Also take a look on [OnActivate](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html) which is also related to these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

My code, for ui-router, has ended up looking something like the following to replace ng1 $rootScope $stateChangeSuccess for Angular2:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TransitionService } from "ui-router-ng2";

@Component({selector: 'app-stage-tag',template: '...'})
class AppComponent {
  constructor(public transitionService: TransitionService){
    transitionService.onSuccess({to:'*'}, transition=>{
      console.log('state', transition._targetState._definition)
      console.log('params', transition._targetState._params)
    })
  }
}
```